# Loop through multiple arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop through a series of `li` elements, and match each element with a color from the `color` array, like so:

```
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var colors = ["salmon", "teal", "orange", "grey", "blue"];

for (i=0; i < li.length; i++) {
li[i].style.backgroundColor=colors[i]

}
```

However, because the length of colours are shorter than the length of the li elements, it stops short.

How can I make the colours array loop through again, until it matches whatever the number of li elements there are?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LhmgQ/)

Answer (score 5):

Use [the `%` modulus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_.28Modulus.29):

```
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var colors = ["salmon", "teal", "orange", "grey", "blue"];
var colorsCount = colors.length;

for ( var i = 0; i < li.length; i++ ) {
    li[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[ i % colorsCount ];
}
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LhmgQ/1/

Comment: It should be `i % colorsCount` actually.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain the logic to that?

Comment: @tmyie - `i % colorsCount` will divide `i` by `colorsCount`, and return the remainder. As long as `i` is less than `colorsCount`, you'll always get back `i`. If `i` is greater than `colorsCount`, you'll get `i` - `colorsCount` (as many times as possible).